# Downloading files with C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

When I am running my method to download a file, it is not waiting for the download to finish before calling the next method "unzipfiles", how could I make it wait until the file is downloaded?

```
private void Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://download1us.softpedia.com/dl/f4932a906a7dd98c7ff002b07e9bd94b/4e065004/100079174/software/portable/security/ccsetup307.zip"), @"ccsetup307.zip");
    // Call unzip method
    unzipfiles();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call your `unzipfiles()` method in DownloadFileCompleted event

Answer (score 2):

You're doing the download asynchronously, which means that the code just starts the download, which is then done in the background. Once the download is completed, the `DownloadFileCompleted` event is fired and your `Completed` method is called.

You should move the call to `unzipfiles` to the `Completed` method.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `DownloadFile()` instead of `DownloadFileAsync()`. However that would mean the UI would be locked up during the download of the files, and you should try to avoid that.

Better solution would be to call `unzipfiles()` from your `Completed()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You should unzip in your `Completed` method:

```
void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    unzipfiles();
}
```

or run download synchronously:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://download1us.softpedia.com/dl/f4932a906a7dd98c7ff002b07e9bd94b/4e065004/100079174/software/portable/security/ccsetup307.zip"), @"ccsetup307.zip");
unzipfiles();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is calling the async implementation of Download File.

For simplicity you can use-

```
webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://download1us.softpedia.com/dl/f4932a906a7dd98c7ff002b07e9bd94b/4e065004/100079174/software/portable/security/ccsetup307.zip"), @"ccsetup307.zip");
```

Without the events registring.

If you want to use the async implementation, this means that when the file is downloaded the WebClient object will call the - *Completed* method - where you can do the Unzip ....